# How do I access the .file array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code as it currently stands. I'm not sure how one can access the .files array of a jquery object or event.

```
var imageSlots = {
    crx: null,
    fileInput: $('<input type="file"/>'),
    imgNode: new Image,
    editingSlot: 1,
    slot1: null,
    slot2: null,
    slot3: null,
    slot4: null
};

$(document)
.on('ready', function(){
    imageSlots.ctx = document.getElementById('editCanvas').getContext('2d');

    imageSlots.fileInput.on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        imageSlots.imgNode.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.files[0]);
    });

    imageSlots.imgNode.onload = function(){
        imageSlots.ctx.drawImage(imageSlots.imgNode, 0,0);
    };

})
.on('click', '.image', function(){
    imageSlots.fileInput.click();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `this.files`, as:

```
....
imageSlots.fileInput.on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    imageSlots.imgNode.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
});
....
```